# how to append numbers into string in php

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a for loop like this in php

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
{
echo $i;
}
```

What I need is, I want to generate roll number using this for loop like this.

```
SN0001  
SN0002  
SN0003  
.....  
SN0010  not SN00010
......  
SN0100  not SN000100
```

I have tried this

```
  <?php
  for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++) {
  $str='SN00'.$i;
  echo $str;
  }
  ?>
```

Note this (SN0010 and SN0100). I need SN0010,SN0100 not SN00010, SN000100.

What should I do for that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I dont know how to do that? That's why asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str_pad()` function:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++) {
  echo 'SN' . str_pad($i, 4, STR_PAD_LEFT, '0');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Please try this code-

    for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++) {
      echo 'SN' .sprintf("%'.04d\n", $i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php
  for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++) {
  $str='SN00'.$i;
  if(strlen($str)<6)
  {
    $str='SN000'.$i;
  }
  if(strlen($str)>6)
  {
    $str='SN0'.$i;
  }
  echo $str;
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
{
    if($i<=9){      
        $zeroValue = '000';
    }
    elseif($i>9 && $i<=99){
        $zeroValue = '00';
    }
    elseif($i>99 && $i<=999){
        $zeroValue = '0';
    }
echo 'SN'.$zeroValue.$i.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: I think this php loop is exactly correct and simple to use.

Comment: well, max value of `$i` is 100, thus, `$i <= 999` is somehow inaccurate (working though).

Comment: I have given a limitation. If a user try to more than this value.